# Making datastore inserts with Google App Engine and WTForms

Tags: python, python-2.x, form, google-app-engine

I have a class for making datastore inserts with Google App Engine and WTForms. Now I want to refactor it into smaller units but I'm not sure how to do it. Can you help me find what needs to be done? The code consists of code for taking a form (AdForm) and its parameters to make a datastore insert. It also checks for inapproriate content in a way I'd like to improve.

```
class AdLister(BaseRequestHandler,
               blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    csrf_protect = False

    def post(self):

        ad = Ad()
        if users.get_current_user():
            ad.user = users.get_current_user()

        if self.current_user is not None:
            try:
                ad.usr = self.current_user
            except Exception, e:
                logging.info('exception %s' % str(e))

        if self.request.get('type'):
            ad.type = self.request.get('type')
        if self.request.get('address'):
            ad.address = self.request.get('address')
        if self.request.get('rooms'):
            ad.number_of_rooms = int(self.request.get('rooms'))
        if self.request.get('size'):
            ad.size = float(self.request.get('size'))
        if self.request.get('regdate'):
            ad.regdate = int(self.request.get('regdate'))
        if self.request.get('mileage'):
            ad.mileage = int(self.request.get('mileage'))

        ad.category = self.request.get('category_group')

        form = AdForm(self.request.params)

        if form.validate():
            title = to_unicode_or_bust(form.title.data)
            #unicode(form.title.data, 'utf-8')
            ad.title = title
            self.session['title'] = ad.title
            name = to_unicode_or_bust(form.name.data)  #, 'utf-8')
            ad.name = name
            self.session['name'] = ad.name
            ad.email = form.email.data
            self.session['email'] = ad.email
            ad.phoneview = form.phoneview.data
            self.session['phoneview'] = ad.phoneview
            try:
                if form.phonenumber.data:
                    ad.phonenumber = form.phonenumber.data
                    self.session['phonenumber'] = ad.phonenumber
            except:
                pass

            text = to_unicode_or_bust(form.text.data)  # , 'utf8')
            titletest = to_unicode_or_bust(form.title.data)

            if 'penis' in text:
                self.response.out.write('REMOVED')
                return

            if 'Black Money' in text:
                self.response.out.write('REMOVED')
                return

            if 'black money' in text:
                self.response.out.write('REMOVED')
                return

            if 'BLACK MONEY' in titletest:
                self.response.out.write('REMOVED')
                return

            if 'BLACK DOLARS' in titletest:
                self.response.out.write('REMOVED')
                return


            if 'Penis' in text:
                self.response.out.write('REMOVED')
                return

            if 'penis' in title:
                self.response.out.write('REMOVED')
                return

            if 'Penis' in title:
                self.response.out.write('REMOVED')
                return

            if 'escort' in text:
                self.response.out.write('REMOVED')
                return
            if 'escorts' in text:
                self.response.out.write('REMOVED')
                return
            if 'escort' in title:
                self.response.out.write('REMOVED')
                return
            if 'escorts' in title:
                self.response.out.write('REMOVED')
                return


            ad.text = text
            self.session['text'] = ad.text
            ad.price = form.price.data.replace(' ', '').replace(',00',
                                                                '').replace('.00', '')
            try:
                if form.price.data:
                    ad.integer_price = form.price.data.replace(' ', ''
                    ).replace(',00', '').replace('.00', '')
            except:
                pass
            self.session['price'] = ad.price
            ad.url = self.request.host
            self.session['url'] = self.request.host
            ad.place = self.request.get('place')
            self.session['place'] = ad.place
            ad.postaladress = self.request.get('place')
            self.session['postaladress'] = ad.postaladress
            ad.put()
            self.session['ad_id'] = ad.key().id()
        else:

            self.render('createnewad.html', {
                'user': self.current_user,
                'session': self.auth.get_user_by_session(),
                'request': self.request,
                'form': form,
                'name': to_unicode_or_bust(form.name.data)  #.encode('utf-8')
            })
            return
        if self.request.get('currency'):
            ad.currency = self.request.get('currency')
            self.session['currency'] = ad.currency
        if self.request.get('cg'):
            ad.category = self.request.get('cg')
            self.session['category'] = ad.category
        if self.request.get('company_ad') == '1':
            ad.company_ad = True
            self.session['company_ad'] = 'True'
        ad.put()

        ad.url = self.request.host

        for upload in self.get_uploads():
            try:
                img = Image(reference=ad)
                img.primary_image = upload.key()
                image_url = images.get_serving_url(str(upload.key()), size=640)
                img.put()
                ad.hasimages = True
                ad.image_url = images.get_serving_url(str(upload.key()), size=640)
                ad.put()
                ad.blobs.append(upload.key())
                ad.put()
            except Exception, e:
                logging.error('There was an exception:%s' % str(e))
                pass
        ad.published = False
        if self.request.get('area'):
            city = \
                montaomodel.City.get_by_id(long(self.request.get('area'
                )))
            region = montaomodel.Region.get(city.region.key())
            ad.cities.append(city.key())
            ad.regions.append(region.key())
            ad.city = unicode(city.name)
            ad.region = unicode(region.name)


        ad.put()
        if self.current_user:
            ad.userID = str(self.current_user.auth_ids[0])
            ad.put()
            ad.usr = self.current_user.key.to_old_key()
            ad.put()

        image = ad.matched_images.get()
        image_url = None
        if image:
            if image.primary_image:
                try:
                    image_url = \
                        images.get_serving_url(str(image.primary_image.key()),
                                               size=640)
                except Exception, e:
                    image_url = '/images/' + str(image.key().id()) \
                                + '_small.jpg'
            else:
                image_url = '/images/' + str(image.key().id()) \
                            + '_small.jpg'
        imv = []
        for i in ad.matched_images:
            if i.primary_image:
                try:
                    i1 = \
                        images.get_serving_url(str(i.primary_image.key()))
                    imv.append(i1)
                except Exception, e:
                    i1 = '/images/' + str(image.key().id()) \
                         + '_small.jpg'
                    imv.append(i1)

        if ad.price:  # and doesn't contain separators
            try:
                price = \
                    i18n.I18n(self.request).format_decimal(int(ad.price))
            except Exception, e:
                price = ad.price
        else:
            price = ad.price

        self.render('preview.html', {
            'user': self.current_user,
            'session': self.auth.get_user_by_session(),
            'request': self.request,
            'ad': ad,
            'image_url': image_url,
            'imv': imv,
            'len': len(imv),
            'form': PreviewAdForm(),
            'price': price,
            })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a massive repetition:

```
if 'penis' in text:
    self.response.out.write('REMOVED')
    return

if 'Black Money' in text:
    self.response.out.write('REMOVED')
    return

if 'black money' in text:
    self.response.out.write('REMOVED')
    return

if 'BLACK MONEY' in titletest:
    self.response.out.write('REMOVED')
    return

if 'BLACK DOLARS' in titletest:
    self.response.out.write('REMOVED')
    return


if 'Penis' in text:
    self.response.out.write('REMOVED')
    return

if 'penis' in title:
    self.response.out.write('REMOVED')
    return

if 'Penis' in title:
    self.response.out.write('REMOVED')
    return

if 'escort' in text:
    self.response.out.write('REMOVED')
    return
if 'escorts' in text:
    self.response.out.write('REMOVED')
    return
if 'escort' in title:
    self.response.out.write('REMOVED')
    return
if 'escorts' in title:
    self.response.out.write('REMOVED')
    return
```

You can use a list comprehension to shorten this very much:

```
BAD_WORDS = ['penis', 'black money', 'escort']

if any([w in text or w.upper() in text or w.capitalize() in text
           for w in BAD_WORDS]):
    self.response.out.write('REMOVED')
    return
```

---

Never use bare `except:`, always tell the expected exception.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still learning python and the way you show is much more concise and better.

Comment: `any[w in text` doesn't look right to me. Shouldn't there be parentheses?

Comment: Please take a bit more care over the code snippets, or this happens: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30168806/3001761

Comment: Wouldn't `w in text.lower()` be more concise and cover all the cases?

Answer (score 3):

## Style

You have commented out bits of code.  Use version control and don't keep
that stuff around (unless you have a very good reason; I don't see one
here).

In some cases the formatting is off.  The general advice is to follow
PEP8, that's very easy to accomplish if you run the corresponding tools,
i.e. `pep8` or so.

## Code

First of all:  You should split your functionality into smaller chunks.
At the moment you have one massive method which does way too many
things.

I'd suggest something along the lines of one method for parsing
input, initialising the `Ad` object, validating input, importing
uploaded files, rendering output, etc.  That way you can later actually
see what the control flow is, because at the moment you have `return`s
mixed into your logic and it's quite confusing to follow.

For filtering certain keywords I'd actually recommend constructing a
regular expression for all words.  That way you can use the features of
the engine to specify patterns more easily than with that loop with
`lower` etc.  It might be more efficient as well since you can
precompile the regex and run it only once on the whole text.  Then
again, if you're still learning maybe just keep what you currently have
and take a look at it later.  See also
e.g. [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750240/how-to-do-re-compile-with-a-list-in-python).

```
import re
BAD_WORDS = ['penis', 'black money', 'escort']
bad_words_regex = re.compile("|".join(BAD_WORDS), re.IGNORECASE)
...
if bad_words_regex.search("some text with BLaCK moNey in it"):
    ...
```

Build helper functions.  If you see a pattern twice (or three times,
whatever your threshold is going to be), then extract it into a
function, method, class, whatever.  But don't repeat yourself.